# Multiple cursors appearing in each cell in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cursor, google-colaboratory, cell

I'm getting a separate cursor for each cell. After execution of one cell, the cursor does not move to the other and when I click on the next cell the cursor appears in previous and present both.
[CLICK TO SEE THE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzLHd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Was researching this problem and found an answer;
the answer happens to be from your post as well!

- Solution 1: Change the default browser ([link](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4761#issuecomment-877907775))
- Solution 2: Reset the browser to factory settings ([link](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4761#issuecomment-878206708))